# Finding the highest value from a field

Tags: mongodb

I have the following object in a mongodb. I'm wanting to find the genre that has won the highest number of awards, and out of the whole collection find the top 3 most found genres. I'm not really sure how to go about targeting specific fields within a collection like this, is it better to treat it as a large array? or is that a ridiculous comment.

Tried query which fails because the genre field is not an accumulator

```
db.MovieData.aggregate([
{$sort:{"awards.wins":-1}},
{$group:{"genres":"$genres"}}
])
```

Example data, there is far more data but i have limited it to 2 insertions

```
[
    {
        "title": "Once Upon a Time in the West",
        "year": 1968,
        "rated": "PG-13",
        "runtime": 175,
        "countries": [
            "Italy",
            "USA",
            "Spain"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Western"
        ],
        "director": "Sergio Leone",
        "writers": [
            "Sergio Donati",
            "Sergio Leone",
            "Dario Argento",
            "Bernardo Bertolucci",
            "Sergio Leone"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Claudia Cardinale",
            "Henry Fonda",
            "Jason Robards",
            "Charles Bronson"
        ],
        "plot": "Epic story of a mysterious stranger with a harmonica who joins forces with a notorious desperado to protect a beautiful widow from a ruthless assassin working for the railroad.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTEyODQzNDkzNjVeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDgyODk1NDEx._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt0064116",
            "rating": 8.6,
            "votes": 201283
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 98,
            "image": "certified",
            "rating": 9,
            "reviews": 54,
            "fresh": 53,
            "consensus": "A landmark Sergio Leone spaghetti western masterpiece featuring a classic Morricone score.",
            "userMeter": 95,
            "userRating": 4.3,
            "userReviews": 64006
        },
        "metacritic": 80,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 4,
            "nominations": 5,
            "text": "4 wins \u0026 5 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    },
    {
        "title": "A Million Ways to Die in the West",
        "year": 2014,
        "rated": "R",
        "runtime": 116,
        "countries": [
            "USA"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Comedy",
            "Western"
        ],
        "director": "Seth MacFarlane",
        "writers": [
            "Seth MacFarlane",
            "Alec Sulkin",
            "Wellesley Wild"
        ],
        "actors": [
            "Seth MacFarlane",
            "Charlize Theron",
            "Amanda Seyfried",
            "Liam Neeson"
        ],
        "plot": "As a cowardly farmer begins to fall for the mysterious new woman in town, he must put his new-found courage to the test when her husband, a notorious gun-slinger, announces his arrival.",
        "poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0NDcyNjg0MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMzk4NTA4MTE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
        "imdb": {
            "id": "tt2557490",
            "rating": 6.1,
            "votes": 126592
        },
        "tomato": {
            "meter": 33,
            "image": "rotten",
            "rating": 4.9,
            "reviews": 188,
            "fresh": 62,
            "consensus": "While it offers a few laughs and boasts a talented cast, Seth MacFarlane's overlong, aimless A Million Ways to Die in the West is a disappointingly scattershot affair.",
            "userMeter": 40,
            "userRating": 3,
            "userReviews": 62945
        },
        "metacritic": 44,
        "awards": {
            "wins": 0,
            "nominations": 6,
            "text": "6 nominations."
        },
        "type": "movie"
    }
```

Comment: Top 3 genres by "total award wins"? Or 3 highest winning movies per each genre? Which of those questions are you actually asking?

Comment: Sorry i meant it more as is there a way to target data in a json object in a particular way, but the question I would like help with is the genre with the highest total wins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
db.MovieData.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$genres" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$genres",
    "totalWins": { "$sum": "$awards.wins" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "totalWins": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 3 }
])
```

In short:

- [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) - The `genres` field is an array, you need that *"flattened"* in order to use as a *"grouping key"* for the next stage:
- [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) - Requires an `_id` which is the *"grouping key"* or the value that things are *accumulated* for. Though not a *requirement* this is typically paired with *accumulators*, which perform the *"aggregation operations"* such as [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) on a supplied field value. Here you want:

  ```
  { "$sum": "$awards.wins" }
  ```

  to accumulate that field.
- [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) - Orders those results by the supplied field(s). In this case on the accumulated `totalWins` and in *descending* ( `-1` ) order.
- [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) - Is the number of result documents to *limit* the return to.

A good place to look for common examples is the [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) in the core documentation, particularly if you have some working knowledge of SQL or even if you do not as general examples.

All of the [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) as well as the [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) also have various usage examples within their own documentation pages as well. Familiarizing yourself with these is useful in understanding how they apply to different problems

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! Maybe a stupid question but can you say use $unwind for multiple keys-if you have to flatten multiple arrays? I.e. say i needed to do something with the countries field as well as the genres

Comment: @chris That would be *separate* `$unwind` stages as that pipeline stage only accepts **one** field as the argument ( all in the linked documentation ). Be careful though since *"multiple unwinds"* can lead to a *cartesian product*. You can [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if there is more you want to do, but also *"search for existing answers"* since that particular issue has certainly been brought up ( and answered ) before.